# How to get max location id of label more faster on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I want to get largest location id of label.

But, It is very slow on follow query.

```
agens=# match (n:v) return max(graphid_locid(id(n)));
 max 
-----
 6
(1 row)
```

How to get max location id of label more faster on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch related sequence value from pg_sequences table.

```
agens=# select start_value from pg_sequences where schemaname = 'graph' and sequencename = 'v_id_seq';
 start_value 
-------------
           6
(1 row)
```